# My Javascript only works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
  var res = document.getElementById('r');

        function ersatzrate() {
            var zinsalt = document.test.zinsalt.value;
            var zeitalt = parseInt(document.test.zeitalt.value);
            var ratealt = parseInt(document.test.ratealt.value);


           var StringText = zinsalt.toString();                      PUNKT
           var AusgabeText = StringText.replace(",",".");
           zinsalt=parseFloat(AusgabeText);

           var zinsneu = document.test.zinsneu.value; 

           var StringText2 = zinsneu.toString();                       PUNKT
           var AusgabeText2 = StringText2.replace(",",".");
           zinsneu=(parseFloat(AusgabeText2)/100/12);

           zinsalt = zinsalt/100/12; Monatszins.

            if (0.21 > zinsalt > 0 && 60 > zeitalt > 0 && 2000 > ratealt > 0 && zinsalt>zinsneu) {

                var rkb = ratealt * zeitalt;               
                document.test.rkb.value = rkb;

                var bw = ratealt * ((Math.pow((zinsalt+1), zeitalt) - 1) / (Math.pow((zinsalt + 1), zeitalt) * zinsalt));  
                var bw = bw.toFixed(2);


                var rateneu =  bw*((Math.pow((zinsneu + 1), zeitalt) * zinsneu)/(Math.pow((zinsneu+1), zeitalt) - 1)); 

                var rateneu = rateneu.toFixed(2);                   
                document.test.rateneu.value = rateneu;


                var rkbneu = rateneu*zeitalt;
                var rkbneu = rkbneu.toFixed(2);
                document.test.rkbneu.value = rkbneu;



                var ersparnis = (rkb-rkbneu);
                var ersparnis = ersparnis.toFixed(2);
                document.test.ersparnis.value = ersparnis;    
            }

        }
```

Link to full code ---> http://jsfiddle.net/3ejwobbu/

I have written a calculator in javascript and it unfortunately only works in chrome and safari. The JS-Fiddle version doesn't work either, any ideas on what is causing this problem?

Comment: what doesn't work?? Are you getting exception etc?

Comment: You'll have to learn how the browser console works. Open the console and see what errors it throws.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? Looks like a syntax error:        zinsalt = zinsalt/100/12; Monatszins.

Comment: Also, things like `0.21 > zinsalt > 0 `. While not technically errors, they most likely don't do what you expect them to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i used

```
document.test.rkb.value = rkb;
```

where I should have used

```
document.getElementById('rkb').innerHTML= rkb;
```

That solved it.